# Bayesian Model(Write out likelihood and prior)

Tags: bayesian, inference, hierarchical-bayesian

I am working with a dataset regarding transmission rate for a disease spreading among cattle at different farms during a 5-month period.

The goal is to estimate the transmission parameter $\alpha$ using a Bayesian model.

I have a dataset with 12 entries(different farms), with the format

| $N$ | $Z_1$ | $Z_2$ | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 17 | 23 | 0 |
| 10 | 5 | 8 | 1 |

where $N$ is the amount of cows tested, $Z_1$ is the amount of infected cows before the period, $Z_2$ is the amount infected after, and the binary variable **Type** is determines if it is a dairy farm(0) or meat farm(1).

I have assumed that the number of newly infected animals during the period follows a Poisson distribution with mean

$$\alpha \frac{SI}{N},$$

where $N$is the number of tested animals, $S$ is the amount of negative at first testing and $I$ is the number of positive at first testing. I also model $\alpha$ as
$$\log(\alpha) = \beta_0 +\beta_1x_i$$ where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ is the type of farm.

I now want to write out a Bayesian model for this(likelihood and prior), with diffuse priors on the parameters. My first idea was to write out the likelihood as

$$\prod_{i=1}^{12} \frac{1}{(Z_{2_i}-Z_{1_i})!}\left(\frac{S_i I_i}{N_i}\exp\{\beta_0 + \beta_1\text{type}_i\} \right)^{Z_{2_i}-Z_{1_i}} \exp\left\{-\frac{S_i I_i}{N_i}\exp\{\beta_0 + \beta_1\text{type}_i\}  \right\}$$

but I am quite unsure. Espescially as how I should write out the prior, but I would also appreciate some help on the likelihood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parameters in your model, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, which are real parameters that can vary from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so the most [uninformative prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Uninformative_priors) that you can use for these parameters would be the improper uniform prior over the real number line, $P(\beta_0,\beta_1) \propto 1$, in which case your expression for the likelihood is the same as the expression for the posterior.

In stan, this model could be expressed like this:

```
data {
  int n_farms;
  int<lower=0> N[n_farms]; // number of cows tested
  int<lower=0> Z1[n_farms]; // number of cows infected before
  int<lower=0> Z2[n_farms]; // number of cows infected after
  int<lower=0,upper=1> type[n_farms]; // whether the farm is dairy (0) or meat (1)
}
transformed data {
  int newly_infected[n_farms];
  for (i in 1:n_farms)
    newly_infected[i] = Z2[i] - Z1[i];
}
parameters {
  real beta0;
  real beta1;
}
transformed parameters {
  vector[n_farms] alpha;
  vector[n_farms] newly_infected_mu;

  for (i in 1:n_farms) {
    alpha[i] = exp(beta0 + beta1 * type[i]);
    newly_infected_mu[i] = alpha[i] * (N[i] - Z1[i]) * Z1[i] / N[i];
  }
}
model {
  // model of newly infected
  newly_infected ~ poisson(newly_infected_mu);
}
```

By omitting an explicit prior on the `beta0`, `beta1` parameters in the `model` block, we are implicitly using the improper uniform prior on these parameters.

However, given that we have very little data available, it would be best to use available domain knowledge to place priors on $\beta_0,\beta_1$ to establish our expectations for the range of values that we might consider to be plausible in the real world. The most uninformative prior that we can apply that would establish a range of reasonable values for each of our parameters would be a normal distribution with a specified mean and standard deviation for each of the parameters that are approximately set based on domain experience. So, we could update our stan model with normal priors to something like this:

```
data {
  int n_farms;
  int<lower=0> N[n_farms]; // number of cows tested
  int<lower=0> Z1[n_farms]; // number of cows infected before
  int<lower=0> Z2[n_farms]; // number of cows infected after
  int<lower=0,upper=1> type[n_farms]; // whether the farm is dairy (0) or meat (1)
  // prior parameters
  real beta0_mu;
  real<lower=0> beta0_sd;
  real beta1_mu;
  real<lower=0> beta1_sd;
}
transformed data {
  int newly_infected[n_farms];
  for (i in 1:n_farms)
    newly_infected[i] = Z2[i] - Z1[i];
}
parameters {
  real beta0;
  real beta1;
}
transformed parameters {
  vector[n_farms] alpha;
  vector[n_farms] newly_infected_mu;

  for (i in 1:n_farms) {
    alpha[i] = exp(beta0 + beta1 * type[i]);
    newly_infected_mu[i] = alpha[i] * (N[i] - Z1[i]) * Z1[i] / N[i];
  }
}
model {
  // priors
  beta0 ~ normal(beta0_mu, beta0_sd);
  beta1 ~ normal(beta1_mu, beta1_sd);
  // model of newly infected
  newly_infected ~ poisson(newly_infected_mu);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, taking the logarithm of the likelihood would simplify the notation.

Using a diffuse prior, i.e. a prior that does not put more probability on some values than on others, does render the Bayesian framework useless. You could work without a prior at all or you could use a more informative prior. For example you could use a uniform prior over an interval in which you are sure to expect $\alpha$ to be part of. There could be even better solutions, but for that I do not have enough domain knowledge.